# PHPExcel set "recent colors"

Tags: excel, phpexcel

I have created a excel template using PHPExcel library. I need users to fill the cells with specific background colors, because in the moment that they upload the template to the server I'll catch those colors and match with some information I have in my database.

My problem is that if I don't export **my background colors** to the pallete of "recent colors", they won't be able to set the current background color in the cell - or they will have tremendous amount of work to find the right color..

[image]

I was hoping I could insert through PHPExcel into the "Recent Colors", so this way all they have to do is one click to choose the right color!

Is it possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No it isn't possible.... "recent colours" aren't stored in the Excel file (your template); they're stored in the Excel application